# uploaded update build for a mac app several times without any problem, but it is still not available

Tags: macos, app-store

It looks like no any problem

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
but after upload the binary file, I wait almost one hour, there is still no any new build option for submission in itunesconnection.

For ios app, I remember that uploaded file will be available within 5 minuts.

Your comment welcome

Comment: On the web site, do you see a button that says "submit for review" or something very similar?  If so, select the uploaded version that you want to submit and then click the button.

Comment: @Phillip Mills there is the button 'submit for review', but no available 'build' to choose